# on click change questions displayed

Tags: php, jquery, refresh

I have a page that has a list of items.  On the bottom of the page is a "view more" button.  When someone clicks this button, the page needs to add more items.  The var is $displayedquestions, and the page is coded right now to refresh when the "view more" button is clicked, but we'd like to have it do it live.  How can this be done?

Here is code:

```
<?php
include "db_connect.php";
db_connect();

function tags($tags)
{
    $tagarray=explode(",",$tags);
    $i=0;
    $finished='false';
    while($finished=='false') {
        if (empty($tagarray[$i])=='true') {
            $finished='true';
        } else {
            $taglist = $taglist . '<a class="commonTagNames" href="">' . $tagarray[$i] . '</a> &nbsp;';
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $taglist;
}


function formattime($timesince)
{
    $strsince=number_format($timesince,0,'','');
    $nodecimals=intval($strsince);
    if ($nodecimals<1){
        return "Less than a minute ago";
    } elseif ($nodecimals>=1&&$nodecimals<60) {
        return $nodecimals . " min ago";
    } elseif ($nodecimals>60&&$nodecimals<1440){
        $hourssince=$nodecimals/60;
        $hoursnodecimals=number_format($hourssince,0);
        return $hoursnodecimals . " hours ago";
    } elseif ($nodecimals>1440){
        $dayssince=$nodecimals/1440;
        $daysnodecimals=number_format($dayssince,0);
        return $daysnodecimals . " days ago";
    }
}

$submitbutton=$_REQUEST['viewmore'];
$numquestions=intval($_REQUEST['questions']);
if($numquestions!=0) {
    $displayedquestions=$numquestions;
} else {
    $displayedquestions=10;
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM `Questions` ORDER BY `Questions`.`ID`  DESC LIMIT 0, " . $displayedquestions;
$questions=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($questions))
{
$id = $row['ID'];
$user = $row['userAsking'];
$question = $row['question'];
$tags = $row['tags'];
$timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
$time=strtotime($timestamp);
$secondssince=(date(U)-$time)/60;
$timesince=formattime($secondssince);
$responses=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `answersToQuestions` WHERE `idOfQuestion`= '$id'");
$comments=mysql_num_rows($responses);
$likes=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `likesOfQuestions` WHERE `idOfQuestion`= '$id'");
$numlikes=mysql_num_rows($likes);
$userprofileq = mysql_query("SELECT `ID`,`avatar` FROM `Users` WHERE `username` = '$user'");
$userprofileresult = mysql_fetch_row($userprofileq);
$linktoprofile = $userprofileresult[0];
$avatar = $userprofileresult[1];
$taglist=tags($tags);

        echo "</li>";


                        echo '<li class="questionsList" onclick="showUser(' . $id  . ')">
                            <div id="questionPadding">
                            <img class="askerImage" width=50 height=50 src="../Images/userimages/' . $avatar . '.png"/>
                            <div class="questionFirstRow"><h1 class="questionTitle">' . $question . '</h1></div>
                            <span class="midRow">
                            <span class="askerSpan"><a class="askerName" href="">'. $user .'</a></span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="bottomRow">                                
                                <img src="../Images/comment.png"/>
                                <span class="comments">' . $comments . '</span>
                                <img src="../Images/likes.png"/>
                                <span class="likes">' . $numlikes . '</span>
                                ' . $timesince . ' 
                            </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>';


}


?>

<center><a href="index.php?questions=<?php  echo $displayedquestions+10; ?>"><img class="moreQuestions" src="../Images/viewMoreBar.png" alt="More" /></a></center>
```

Comment: u have to use jQuery read more [plugin](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/02/more-showing-more-hiding)

Comment: oh, so do you think the page should load all of the items, which could be a huge amount, and then just collapse them or something.  I know how to do that with jquery but that seems like server overload.

Comment: What do you mean by "do it live"?

Comment: That's a pretty tall order.  I was able to find a blog post that has a nice example that you might be able to glean some direction from:  http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2581

Comment: ur tag function can b wriiten like this `function tags($tags)
{
 $tagarray=explode(",",$tags);
 $i=0;
 $taglist='';
 foreach($tagarray as $key)
 {
  $taglist .= '<a class="commonTagNames" href="">' . $key . '</a> &nbsp;';
  $i++;
 }
 return $taglist;
}`

Comment: If you need to keep the current items shown there..? or is it something like a pagination..?

Answer (score 2):

Without doing a lot of work you can add ajax to this.  Use this function:

First, (I am assuming you are including the code above into another file) create a container around it. Ex:

```
<div id='container'>...</div>
```

Second, add this javascript to the page that includes the code you have above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#container img.moreQuestions").parent().live('click', (function (e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#container").load($(this).attr("href"));
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will load into `#container` the script you already have without refreshing the rest of the page.

**Note** the selector for the `More` link (slash button) in my example is `$("#container img.moreQuestions").parent()` because you don't have a class or id on it.  You should give a class or id to the `More` link and use that for the selector.

Answer (score 0):

like @diEcho mentioned, jQuery would be a great help: You could easily refresh your list of items by ajax (retrieving the complete list from a  php file for example) as well as update your DOM elements with newly added values. Give it a try.
In addition you should think about getting you initial items by ajax as well. Data logic /display /UI functionality were seperated cleanly this way.